# extracting the information from graph_from_polygon OSMNX

Tags: python, geometry, geopandas, qgis, osmnx

I'm trying to get the graph of a city and some surrounding areas, for which I have the .shp file from QGIS and I know it works. I want to extract the graph from the polygon and then plot some routes in that graph. gif_umkreis is a GeoDataframe

```
    import geopandas as gpd
    import osmnx as ox

    gif_umkreis = gpd.read_file('Gifhorn_umkreis_3857.shp')
    gif_umkreis = gif_umkreis.to_crs(4326)
    transport_mode = "drive"
    G = ox.graph_from_polygon(gif_umkreis, network_type=transport_mode, simplify=True)
```

I got this error:

```
    ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I saw a post with the same issue, I know the graph_from_polygon function expects the polygon argument the so I changed the code a bit based on the answer:

```
    polygon_G = gif_umkreis.iloc[0]['geometry']
    G = ox.graph_from_polygon(polygon_G, network_type=transport_mode, simplify=True)
```

polygon_G works of course. But only gives me the geometry of the first row as a polygon. What I actually need is the whole geometry. Like this:

```
    pol_G = gif_umkreis['geometry']
    G = ox.graph_from_polygon(pol_G, network_type=transport_mode, simplify=True)
```

but the type of Pol_G won't be a polygon anymore and is a GeoSeries. From this point ox.graph_from_polygon won't work anymore.I know it's because pol_G is of GeoSeries type. Is there maybe an alternative way?

Comment: Why not just call `unary_union` on the GeoSeries?

Answer (score 0):

As noted in comments, to collapse all geometries in a GeoDataFrame or GeoSeries into a single shapely geometry object, use the attribute [`geopandas.GeoSeries.unary_union`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.unary_union.html#geopandas.GeoSeries.unary_union). In your case:

```py
G = ox.graph_from_polygon(
    gif_umkreis.unary_union, network_type=transport_mode, simplify=True
)
```

Comment: thank you so much. I tried it and it worked.